# How to get UITextField values when button is clicked

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have this view:

[image]

and these implementations:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableLogin dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
            UITextField *textfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 165, 30)];
            textfield.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            textfield.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            textfield.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            textfield.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
            textfield.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
            textfield.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            textfield.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
            textfield.delegate = self;

            if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
                textfield.tag = 0;
                textfield.placeholder = @"your username";
                textfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
                textfield.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
            }
            else {
                textfield.tag = 1;
                textfield.placeholder = @"required";
                textfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
                textfield.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
                textfield.secureTextEntry = YES;
            }

            [textfield setEnabled:YES];
            [cell addSubview:textfield];
            [textfield release];
        }
    }
    if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
        if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Email";
        }
        else {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Password";
        }
    }

    return cell;    
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    switch (textField.tag) {
        case 0:
            self.username = textField.text;
            break;
        case 1:
            self.password = textField.text;
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

When the user click Login button without tap "Done" for close the keyboard it doesn't save the field values. How can I tricky-fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

Keep a reference to both textfields and pull their `text` values in the "Done" button's action method.

Alternatively, register for the `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` and capture input as it happens.

Comment: What's `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` ? I can't find anything of it.

Comment: It's a notification name defined for UITextField. You would register for it like this: `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:textField];`

Comment: Docs *are* oddly sparse. Page 22 of this *PDF* lists all of the notifications supported by the class: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/UITextField_Class.pdf

Comment: What's change by `[textfield addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)
                        forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];` ? Which one's better?

Comment: Oh, interesting, I suppose that would work, too. Dunno, try both, see which is tidier for you. As long as you get the data you're looking for, either approach seems sound.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` and save your values there, in addition to hitting the return key.

Comment: I made a change on my side to use IBAction instead of void. -(IBAction)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField and I referenced the "Editing Changed" event to this action. Worked like a charm.